# Citation order by year

Tags: citing, sorting

I'm fairly new to LaTeX so this question may come off as trivial, but how would one go about sorting the elements within a citation by year?

For example, my citation would read in alphabetical order as (Frank, 2007; James, 2005; John, 1998). Where/what would I need to change to have it read (John, 1998; James, 2005; Frank, 2007)?

edit: I'm using natbib and a custom bibliostyle. Is it possible to leave the bibliography portion untouched (as the one that's displaying for me is perfect) and only tinker with the elements within the citation?

Comment: What bibliography package are you using, if any? Are you using [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) or perhaps [`natbib`](http://ctan.org/pkg/natbib)?

Comment: If you're using [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex), you can see [`biblatex`: how to sort references by year within the citation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55256/5764). Give some feedback after reviewing the linked question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you may see [this](https://github.com/plessl/latex-goodies/tree/master/bibstyles/plainyr-rev) for further details on answering your question,

I'll summarize some of their answer in here,

- there is a user package for sorting references either chronologically or reverse chronologically, [plesslweb](http://blog.plesslweb.ch/post/6628963116/bibtex-style-for-sorting-in-reverse-chronological-order)
- you can also use [biblatex](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/biblatex.html) for ordering your references by year or
- [natbib](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/natbib.html),

All them may be fairly easy to use considering you are new to latex.
Btw, [Welcome to TeX.sx!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)