# Sorting bibliography by year

Tags: bibtex, sorting

Is there a package to sort a bibliography by date and not by author?  I cannot find a definitive answer.

Comment: Please link to one of the non-definitive ones...

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55256/65056

Comment: That is one - I will find some more examples

Comment: Why is the q/A you linked not ok? We need to know this to suggest another solution.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided a little more guidance about the requirements.  If it is to be sorted by year, does that mean the first 'element' of an entry will be the year?  I.e., something like: `year. name. title. publishing info.`? (If not, and a standard `.bbx` style is otherwise fine, you could easily 'fake' a year sorting scheme by adding a `sortname` field to each entry (via `\DeclareSourcemap`) and then use a typical `nyt` or `ydnt` sorting scheme.  But the bibligraphy would be virtually unusable, I think....)