# Sort references within citation by year in biblatex-chicago

Tags: sorting, biblatex-chicago

I use `\cite` to refer to multiple sources. I want them to be sorted in text by year of publishing, but I want the bibliography to keep its normal sorting (alphabetical).

currently using this settings

```
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber,autolang=other,%
bibencoding=auto,footmarkoff]{biblatex-chicago}
```

Tried also [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55256/biblatex-how-to-sort-references-by-year-within-the-citation) solution, but that doesn't work.

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/361031/35864 help?

Comment: Any news here? Did the linked answer help you? If not, what did you try and how exactly did it not work for you? Please show us an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) in case the answer did not work for you.